# All my Js are called in the body, how can I fix that situation?

Tags: 6, javascript

I a have a drupal 6 website to fix. All the scripts are called in the body, even with the scope value set to "header" or "footer" in the drupal_add_js function.

It's a problem because some script are called before Jquery and doesn't works.

What i want to do is :

-> Call each script in the proper place (header or footer)
-> Call the scripts in correct order

Drupal do it well on my other sites, so i have to found what generate that situation.

So my question is : how can i test my website to find the problem? Do you have idea, suggestions? Do you have ever meet that situation? Thx you.

Comment: This is probably the result of a mangled page.tpl.php file. You should be able to fix it easily enough by comparing the script output in the standard page.tpl.php to your own

Comment: That is a good lead.

Comment: I rebuild a clean page.tpl.php and a page-front.tpl.php. All works well.